# Executing script on EC2 spot instances remotely

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a Ruby script that calls a shell script on an EC2 AMI that I would like to start on launch of the EC2 spot instance.

In the past I've used Ruby's Net::SSH to SSH into the instance once it launched to run the script, but I don't have my old example code in front of me - can anyone point me in the right direction?

Launching the script on startup would work as well.

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 1):

You could use user data with cloud init directives to pass script to your instance on boot.

When you create an instance pass cloud init configuration like below:

```
#cloud-config
repo_update: true
repo_upgrade: all

packages:
 - ruby

runcmd:
  - /usr/bin/ruby -e '...'
```

See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html#user-data-shell-scripts for the documentation*

Comment: Documentation for spot instances mentions user data: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/request-spot-instances.html

Also as far as I can see from AWS console, when selected spot instance, user data entry box is still available, not disabled.